# Is it appropriate to cast ContentPresenter.Content to UIElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, contentpresenter, uielement

Are there any situations where the content of a `ContentPresenter` will be some object other than a `UIElement`? Given that the field is declared as object rather than a `UIElement`, it seems possible that there would be. However, I cannot think of any situations where it would be, or even if it would be valid.

```
ContentPresenter presenter = GetTemplateChild(PART_Presenter) as ContentPresenter;
UIElement myElement = (UIElement)presenter.Content;
myElement.SomeUIMethod(); // possible InvalidOperationException?
```

Comment: You will get an InvalidCastException in the 2nd line, not and InvalidOperationException on the third

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do it all the time - and the entire MVVM method is built on non-`UIElement` content, here is an example:

Create a class that isn't derived from `UIElement`, I'll call is MyViewModelClass in this example.

Create a Window and add this code

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        DataContext = new MyViewModelClass();
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
}
```

And add some content control to the XAML:

```
<Button Content="{Binding}"/>
```

Now you have a `ContentPresenter` (inside the Button control template) with MyViewModelClass as the Content.

Another (maybe more common) example is `ItemControl` - let's take a `ListBox` for example, each `ListBoxItem` has a `ContentPresenter` that has whatever was in the list set to `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that was the case

Answer (score 4):

Here's the most basic example I can think of

```
<Label Content="My Label" />
```

Now the content property is a string which doesn't derive from `UIElement`. So the short answer is yes, it's not only possible, it's likely to happen.